# Как отправить результат FSM состояния, пользователю по user id?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Всем доброй ночи, у меня есть результат работы FSM состояния:

```
        data = await state.get_data()
        await message.answer(f"ФИО: {data['fuul_name']}\n"
                            f"телефон: {data['number_contact']}\n"
                            f"адрес: {data['address']}\n"
                            f"Время: {data['first_time_last']}\n"
                            f"Причина: {data['reason']}\n"
                            f"Дата: {now.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')}")

        await state.finish()
```

Мне нужно отправить этот результат определённому пользователю по user id, что бы результат ввода пользователя в боте, пришел в ЛС пользователю, ну к примеру **админу бота информация собранная в FSM состоянии**. Как это можно реализовать, *и если вообще возможно это реализовать* подскажите пожалуйста, буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: `bot.send_message(chat_id=..., text="text")` вместо `...` ставь свой юзер айди. Только помни что бот не может первым начинать разговор с юзером

Comment: @oleksandrigo огромное спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @oleksandrigo а как отправить через bot.send_message сообщение в чат?

Comment: Ну так вместо юзер айди пиши чайт айди чата

Comment: @oleksandrigo блин..... точно, спасибо!